# How to use obj file at ARCore with new version of android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm using:

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1
```

now I want to render an obj file.
each obj file have three files:

1. obj file
2. mtl file
3. a jpg/png file

In previous versions of Android Studio I used to convert these 3 files into one file (sfb).

1. Install the Google Sceneform Tools plugin from plugins.
2. Create a sampleData folder in your project's app folder.
3. Copy your 3D model source asset file (three files)
4. Right-click the 3D model and select Import Sceneform Asset.
5. Change the path or name as per the requirements.
6. Click Finish to begin the import process.
7. You will find the .sfb file at the location that you mentioned in the fifth point.

then I used this file to render my 3d file (the my texture was inside of this sfb file.)
but this version not supported `Google Sceneform Tools plugin`.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin is outdated since 2020 I guess, same with the Library.
An up to date Library based on the old one can be found here https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android
The SFB-Support has been abandoned. The new kid on block is called glb/gltf. If you know Blender you can convert your OBJ-files to GLB-files https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html
If you have still questions feel free to join the SceneView Discord-Server https://discord.gg/UbNDDBTNqb